# copy a named range in one excel sheet to a named range in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have been attempting to copy a named range in one excel sheet to a named range in another worksheet

```
Sub Update()
'update availability and utilisation to SMU Tracking sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws1 As Worksheet:
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Delays_a") 'source

Dim ws2 As Worksheet:
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("SMU Tracking") 'destination

'copy
ws1.Range("Productivity").Copy
ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU").Select
ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU").Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Update:

I also tried this code

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'update availability and utilisatioon to SMU Tracking sheet

Dim ws1 As Worksheet:
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Delays_a") 'source

Dim ws2 As Worksheet:
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("SMU Tracking") 'destination

'copy
ws1.Range("Productivity").Copy 'cells to copy

lrow = 1500000
For i = 5 To lrow
    If Cells(i, 7) = "" Then 'If cell is empty then paste new value
    ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that the values are pasted to all the empty cells in Range("ProductivitySMU").

Comment: `ws1.Range("Productivity").Copy ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU")` should work if both ranges are of the same size. Else, try `ws1.Range("Productivity").Copy ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU").Cells(1)`. Avoid `Select` and consider what might be the difference if ScreenUpdating were not disabled (answer: no difference).

Comment: Ah, yes. The problem is that the ranges are not the same size. Range("Productivity") has 10 rows and Range("ProducivitySMU") has 134 rows. What you suggested helped but it copied the data to all the blank ranges in Range("ProducivitySMU").

Comment: The new data will over-write the existing. Where, in the target range do you want the new data? What about the remaining, pre-existing, which aren't over-written?

Comment: To answer this question "Where, in the target range do you want the new data? What about the remaining, pre-existing, which aren't over-written?"  I want the data in Range("Productivity") to got to the next blank cell in Range(""ProducivitySMU"). I hope I'm explaining myself clearly.

Comment: I revised my solution below to accommodate this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. It appends the new data to pre-existing content of the target range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'update availability and utilisatioon to SMU Tracking sheet
    
    Dim ws1     As Worksheet                    ' source
    Dim ws2     As Worksheet                    ' destination
    Dim Rt      As Long                         ' target row
    Dim Ct      As Long                         ' target column
    
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Delays_a")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("SMU Tracking")
    
    With ws2.Range("ProductivitySMU")
        Ct = .Column
        Rt = ws2.Cells(.Row, Ct).End(xlDown).Row + 1
        If Rt > ws2.Rows.Count Then Rt = .Row
    End With
    ws1.Range("Productivity").Copy
    With ws2.Cells(Rt, Ct)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

In essence, the target range isn't required to be named because the code just uses the name to find the target cell. In fact, the name would become irrelevant if the total rows in its column exceed the number of rows it is specified with. For purposes of my code the relevant member of the target range is its first cell. If you have another use for that range in your project you might make it dynamic, expanding automatically to the end of the column, without affecting this code's functioning.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. It works. I need it to paste the values instead of the formulas.

Comment: .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues does not work for me with this code.

Comment: No. PasteSpecial needs different syntax. I've modified my answer to deploy `PasteSpecial`. The code now also doesn't crash if *ProductivitySMU* is blank :-)

Comment: Thanks, I figured.